# Accessibilityservice cannot click a button

Tags: java, android, automation

I wrote a code to click a button from accessibilityservice, it works fine for other buttons, but this button is tricky, it forces user to wait 3s before it's clickable
I can't click it from accessibilityservice, even if I wait 3s it's still not clicking
here's my code

```
    if (event.getSource() != null) {
        if (event.getPackageName().equals("com.mrsool")) {
            AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo = event.getSource();

            if (nodeInfo == null) {
                return;
            }
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                // We can find button using button name or button id
                List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> list = nodeInfo
                        .findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("com.mrsool:id/fllwillDeliver");

                for (AccessibilityNodeInfo node : list) {

                    node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
                }

                list = nodeInfo.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("com.mrsool:id/fllwillDeliver");
                for (AccessibilityNodeInfo node : list) {
                    node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);


                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing

```
    findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId
```

to

```
    findAccessibilityNodeInfosByText
```